# Phone Numbers In RTL Layouts

Tags: html, css

When adding a phone number like `+ 972-123888555` in a right-to-left layout, the plus symbol will be positioned at the end of the number.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix that, reassign the direction of the phone number.

```
p {
    direction: ltr;
}
```